# Detect Backbone model validation for any undesired attributes

Tags: node.js, validation, backbone.js, backbone.validation.js

I implemented this simple feature to detect any undesired or unspecified attributes in a Backbone Model:

```
var Underscore = require( '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/underscore' ),
    Backbone = require( '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/backbone' ),
    Validation = require( '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/backbone-validation' );

Underscore.extend( Backbone.Model.prototype, Validation.mixin );

var User = Backbone.Model.extend( {
   validation: {
        firstname: {
            minLength: 1,
            maxLength: 20,
            required: true
        },
        lastname: {
            minLength: 1,
            maxLength: 20,
            required: true
        }
    }, 
    ...

    isAttributeAccepted: function( attr ) {
        var retval = false;
        for ( var property in this.validation ) {
            if ( attr == property ) {
                retval = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return retval;
    },
    ...
```

In use:

```
var user = new User();
var isDesired = user.isAttributeAccepted( "nop" );
console.log( isDesired ) // false;
```

I only done it because I cannot find anything in the Backbone.validation to replace this.
How could I replace this code with a prefered way to use Backbone.validation (github thederson.com) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found methods in `backbone.validation` to do it, but you can write your code a little bit easier:

```
    isAttributeAccepted: function(attr) {
        return _.has(this.validation, attr);
    },
```

Comment: This is an improvement. Thanks.